# Is it possible to use an array with the OrderBy method?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I would like to OrderBy the var 'StorageLocation' in a table from a SQL query and sort it by a defined array.

My Array: `string[] sortedLocations = {"Location A", "Location B", "Location 2"};`

What I tried: `reportRecords.OrderBy(o => o.StorageLocation == sortedLocations[o])`

This code currently has the desired results. It will order by the StorageLocations I set first, then append the rest to the end. It's just a bit tedious when I change/reorder a StorageLocation.

```cs
public void ActiveReport_ReportStart()
{
    // Create report query and set the report datasource
    using (var context = sqlDB.CreateContext())
    {
        var reportRecords = (from ii in context.IssuedItems
                                where (ii.Item.BarcodeId.Length == 9)
                                select new
                                {
                                    ii.Item.StorageLocation,
                                    ii.Item.BarcodeId,
                                    ii.User.UsernameId
                                }).ToList();
        reportRecords = reportRecords.OrderBy(o =>
            // Order by defined StorageLocation first
            o.StorageLocation == "Location A" ? 1 :
            o.StorageLocation == "Location B" ? 2 :
            o.StorageLocation == "Location 2" ? 3 : 4
            ).ThenBy(o => o.BarcodeId).ToList();
        rpt.DataSource = reportRecords;
    }
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated! :)

Would something like this be more effective?

```cs
List<reportRecords> definedLocations = new List<reportRecords>() 
{
    "Location A",
    "Location B",
    "Location 2"
};

List<reportRecords> sorted = (from e in definedLocations
    orderby e.BarcodeId
    select e).ToList();
```

Comment: You could make it a `Dictionary<string, int> { [1] = "Location A", [2] = ...}` and then it would just be `OrderBy(o => sortedLocations.GetValueOrDefault(o.StorageLocation, 4))`

Comment: @juharr thank you for the reply.  I was trying to get away from the index numbers in the array and just sorted it based on the first element.  I have a lot of locations in an SQL database and I may need to amend the array to have a different location appear before "Location A", so I would like to easily add it to the top. I edited the post for hopefully a clearer example.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a implementation of an IComparer as a second parameter to OrderBy.  Then in that Comparer, you can add logic to use your array as the comparison.

Notes: I'm sure you could make my "left/right" more efficient, but it does the trick. I did it that way so unfound elements would be placed at the end. You could also fallback to a regular string comparison for elements not in the list after knowing they come afterwards.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mylist = new List<string> { "Location 2", "Location A", "Location B", "Location X" };
    mylist = mylist.OrderBy(t => t, new MyComparer()).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", mylist));
}

class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    List<string> MyOrder = new List<string> { "Location A", "Location 2", "Location B" };

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var left = MyOrder.IndexOf(x) == -1 ? int.MaxValue : MyOrder.IndexOf(x);
        var right = MyOrder.IndexOf(y) == -1 ? int.MaxValue : MyOrder.IndexOf(y);
        return left - right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
// create array for locations to order reportRecords by
String[] definedLocations = {
    "Location A", 
    "Location B", 
    "Location 2"
};

// create a table then add the array definedLocations
var sortedLocations = new List<String>();
sortedLocations.AddRange(definedLocations);
```

~

```
// IndexOf is used to match strings in sortedLocations with StorageLocations
reportRecords = reportRecords.OrderBy(o => sortedLocations.IndexOf(o.StorageLocation)).ToList();
```

The only undesirable effect in my situation is that any location not listed in `definedLocations`, is placed at the top of the list. So if `StorageLocation` has "Location Y", it would come before "Location A".

That will be a fight for another day. Thank you to those who commented.